# How to show Jade errors when it runs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I'm new to Jade and I'm having errors, how can I see them?

Some questions in stackoverflow shows the full exception but where can i see mine? this is an example:

```
12| .well
13| - if (error)
> 14| p= error
15| form(role='form',action='sessions', method='post')
16| .form-group
17| label(for='Email') Eposta Adresi
Invalid indentation, you can use tabs or spaces but not both
at Object.Lexer.indent (C:\Nodejs\NodejsBlog\node_modules\jade\lib\lexer.js:691:15)
at Object.Lexer.next (C:\Nodejs\NodejsBlog\node_modules\jade\lib\lexer.js:789:15)
at Object.Lexer.lookahead (C:\Nodejs\NodejsBlog\node_modules\jade\lib\lexer.js:122:46)
at Object.Parser.lookahead     (C:\Nodejs\NodejsBlog\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:116:23)
at Object.Parser.parseCode   (C:\Nodejs\NodejsBlog\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:311:17)
at Object.Parser.parseExpr (C:\Nodejs\NodejsBlog\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:225:21)
at Object.Parser.block (C:\Nodejs\NodejsBlog\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:593:25)
at Object.Parser.tag (C:\Nodejs\NodejsBlog\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:722:26)
at Object.Parser.parseTag (C:\Nodejs\NodejsBlog\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:625:17)
at Object.Parser.parseExpr (C:\Nodejs\NodejsBlog\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:199:21)
```

How can I get a similar alert? is that a nodejs configuration option???

Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't have to configure anything. If there are errors in your Jade template, you will see them when you try to go to a page that renders that template.

Comment: then I don't know where I should get that message, I though it was in the console where I type "node app.js", thanks!

Comment: The error message should come in your console as well as the page you open in your browser.

Comment: I can see the page but not the error. I don't get it, thanks

Comment: If you can see your page fine, are you sure you have an error in your jade code?

Comment: you are right! thanks. the problem was this: app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});